Ocelot Gateway Swagger does not display service endpoints
I am working with microservice architecture. I have so much services registered to my api gateway (ocelot). I don't want to open and check the each service swagger for endpoints. Instead I want to see them from single swagger
Ocelot is able to find my port but not showing the controller enpoint of my microservices (I can also reach and make operations with using gateway url/{service})
Previous program.cs of gateway (enpoints are usable, this version is before the swagger implementation, just for single url usage)
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Adding configuration for Ocelot
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

// Adding Ocelot to the services collection
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

// Using Ocelot middleware
app.UseOcelot().Wait();

app.Run();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

Program.cs of gateway
using MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddSwaggerForOcelot(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API Gateway", Version = "v1" });
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseSwaggerForOcelotUI(opt =>
{
    opt.PathToSwaggerGenerator = "/swagger/docs";
    opt.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; 
});

app.UseOcelot().Wait();

app.Run();

Example endpoint in ocelot.json
"SwaggerEndPoints": [
    {
      "Key": "user",
      "Config": [
        {
          "Name": "User Service",
          "Version": "v1",
          "Url": "http://localhost:5496/swagger/v1/swagger.json"
        }
      ]
    }, ...goes on

How I reach my services as example:
 "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5496
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": ["GET"]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/get",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5496
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user/get",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": ["POST"]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/list",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5496
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user/list",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": ["POST"]
    }, ...goes on

I can also able to use swagger in each service without problem. But in case, I will share each version that I use while trying to reach the endpoints to show in swagger in gateway.
Service program.cs ( I am able to use swagger without the commented lines, these commented lines just for some test to display endpoints in gateway -didn't work-)
using App;
using App.Controller;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.SetServices(typeof(Program).Assembly);

#region Custom codes
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Infrastructure.DB.Context.DefaultContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<App.Query.Queries>();

// builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
// {
//     c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "User Service API", Version = "v1" });
// });

var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var eventBus = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MQ.Service>();
eventBus.Subscribe<App.Command.Event.Request, App.Command.Event.Request_Handler, App.Command.Event.Request>(serviceProvider, "service.User");



#endregion

var app = builder.Build();

// if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
// {
//     app.UseSwagger();
//     app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
//     {
//         c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "User Service API V1");
//     });
// }

app.SetApp();
app.SetControllers();
app.Run();

